# Finding a critic point using lagrange multipliers

Tags: real-analysis, lagrange-multiplier

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\;$ be defined as follows:

$\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^n \; f(x)= x_1x_2...x_n$

I need to find a point $a = (a_1,...a_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n\;$ such that $a$ is a critic point of $f$ under the following restrictions:

$\forall 1\leq i \leq n \; a_i \neq 0$

$x_1 + ... + x_n = n$

I started by calculating the gradient of $f$:

$\nabla f=\left(\begin{array}{c}
x_{2}x_{3}...x_{n}\\
x_{1}x_{3}...x_{n}\\
\vdots\\
x_{1}x_{2}...x_{n-1}
\end{array}\right)$

then I defined $g(x) = x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n -n \;$ as my restriction function, we have that:

$\nabla g=\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
1\\
\vdots\\
1
\end{array}\right)$

I was having trouble solving the system $\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g\;$ under the above restrictions though.

Would love to get some help.

Answer (score 1):

From $\nabla f=\lambda\nabla g$ you obtain a system of $n$ equations with high symmetry. The first equation is
$$x_2x_3\ldots x_n=\lambda\ .$$
Multiply this equation with $x_1$, and obtain
$$p:=\prod_ix_i=\lambda x_1\ .$$
In the same way you obtain $n$ equations
$$p=\lambda x_j\qquad(1\leq j\leq n)\ .$$
This allows to conclude that a conditionally critical point with all $x_i\ne0$ has $x_1=x_2=\ldots=x_n$, and therefore $x_i=1$ $\>(1\leq i\leq n)$.